# How to run multiple Delete sql statement with the help of java JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to delete three different tables at once and I have create a pretty simple SQL statement for that matter as following :

```
DELETE FROM tbl1;DELETE FROM tbl2;DELETE FROM tbl3;
```

this statement is correct when I run in mysql directly but from java no!

my java code :

```
public boolean clearTables()
     {
         boolean ans = false;
         if (con != null)
         {
             try
             {
                String deleteQuery = "    DELETE FROM tbl1;DELETE FROM tbl2;DELETE FROM tbl3;";
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                st.execute(deleteQuery);

                ans = true;
             }
             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ans= false;
             }
         }
         return ans;
     }
```

how can I run multiple SQL statements at once in java?

Comment: The `delete` statements you mentioned in your question are not executed at once. They are executed in turn in the sequence you provided.

Answer (score 8):

Use `addBatch` then `executeBatch`:

```
   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   st.addBatch("DELETE FROM tbl1");
   st.addBatch("DELETE FROM tbl2");
   st.addBatch("DELETE FROM tbl3");
   int[] results = st.executeBatch();
```

Then `results` will contain an array with the number of rows deleted from each table.

Answer (score 2):

use batch updates

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec2/jdbc2.1.frame6.html